# Unable to change Sylius Promotion code field

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

We updated to Sylius `0.17` lately, which introduced the immutable `code` field on quite some entities. We only use the `promotion` part at the moment, which is part of our Symfony standard application.

- The form (`PromotionType`) adds a `AddCodeFormSubscriber` eventsubscriber.
- The entity has an 'unique' validator to show exception messages in the form.

If our Controller updates the Promotion after it was saved, it isn't changed so I'm missing some classes that affect this because of the immutability. But, I can not find out what happens exactly.

As a result of that, the form keeps on throwing an error because the code is not unique. So, how can I configure some sort of generator for the Sylius `code` field?

**Edit:** We've migrated the existing data by setting `code` to "prefix+id". The form subscriber actually adds a field which has `1` as a value. So, somehow the value is set. If we save the promotion, and afterwards add another one, the `code` field still is set to `1`. What exactly does determine this value should be set to `1`? The form does not respect the `Promotion::setCode()` we manually did before binding the entity to the form.

Comment: Have you checked your console and watched everything using breakpoints and looking into each part of the code?

Comment: Yes, even tried to set the `code` to another value after it was changed. If it really is immutable there isn't any trace about that, and it should throw an `Exception` if it actually is changed right? I'm going to look into the events tomorrow: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/general/events.html

Comment: Apologies, I'm don't really use Sylius, sorry I can't be of any help